# What is the reason for getting error 1054?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

Getting this error while inserting data into the table.

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column '1' in 'field list'

I'm using **MySQL Server 5.6.***.

I already looked at a lot of threads on StackOverflow and a lot of articles on the Internet, but still, I just don’t understand how to make this query work for me.

I've already tried:

1. not to set the `PlayerID` value myself
2. to leave it totally out from the query, but then I get another error 1064

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PLAYERS` (
      `PlayerID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `FirstName` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
      `LastName` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
      `NickName` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
      `Gender` CHAR(1) NULL,
      `BirthDate` DATE NULL,
      `TeamID` INT NULL,
      `CountryID` INT NOT NULL,
      INDEX `FirstName_idx` (`FirstName` ASC),
      INDEX `LastName_idx` (`LastName` ASC),
      INDEX `NickName_idx` (`NickName` ASC),
      INDEX `TeamID_idx` (`TeamID` ASC),
      INDEX `CountryID_idx` (`CountryID` ASC),
      PRIMARY KEY (`PlayerID`),
      CONSTRAINT `TeamID`
        FOREIGN KEY (`TeamID`)
        REFERENCES `CSGO`.`TEAMS` (`TeamID`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
      CONSTRAINT `PlayerCountryID`
        FOREIGN KEY (`CountryID`)
        REFERENCES `CSGO`.`COUNTRIES` (`CountryID`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

```
INSERT INTO `PLAYERS` (`PlayerID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `NickName`, `Gender`, `BirthDate`, `TeamID`, `CountryID`) 
   VALUES (1, 'Fatih', 'Dayik', 'gob b', 'M', '1987-07-10', NULL, 80);
INSERT INTO `PLAYERS` (`PlayerID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `NickName`, `Gender`, `BirthDate`, `TeamID`, `CountryID`) 
   VALUES (2, 'Nikola', 'Ninic', 'LEGIJA', 'M', '1990-11-15', NULL, 216);
```

[DB STRUCTURE HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=2392c19dd392d38d205ad7d2d6a493a6)

Comment: As I said, I tried not to set it up, but I get syntax error.

Comment: [Works for me.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=013002386d3495e1805a9092a3966b7a)

Comment: without the foreign keys irt works, as you didn't provide also the ither tables with data. it is not reproducable

Comment: I added a [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=2392c19dd392d38d205ad7d2d6a493a6) to my structure

Comment: @nbk foreign key error would result in a different error message, not unknown column.

Comment: @worker is there a trigger on the player table?

Comment: @Shadow yes. [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=a209b5331f2e68d13d1cc039b03bdfea)

Comment: DB-FIDDLE is not helping - you don't need to set delimiters in db-fiddle

Comment: @P.Salmon It isn't about delimiters, foreign keys, triggers nor auto-increment. There is just some bug with the first row. If I mark it as a comment, everything works fine.

Comment: Ok guys, thank you all for your comments. I found the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find out the reason which occurs that error code.

I exported all inserts of `Players` table to an external CSV-file and found the following issue.

[image: Excel vs Notepad++]

There were some hidden characters just before `1` that Notepad++ didn't show up. 
Removing extra characters resolved the situation.